# Tkinter background visible through image

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-label

Below is the output of my tkinter code to display image

[image: background showing through image]

Here, you can see the terminal in the background showing

[image: image not showing through at all1]

since the tkinter window is on top of textpad which is white, the image is not visible

1. In my first attempt,

I tried setting an attribute where I set the transparency. That did not work.

```
image.attributes('-alpha',1.0)
```

Here, 1.0 is for opaque (as opposed to 0.0 which is for full transparency).

2. In my second attempt,

I am trying to overlay my image over a green background. That also does not work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Canvas, PhotoImage, Label

root = tk.Tk()

# creat the root window
root.geometry("800x400")
root.attributes('-alpha',1.0)
root.title("Image on backGround")
root.resizable(False, False)

backGround = Canvas(root, bg="#006400", height=400, width=800)

getImage = PhotoImage(file='/s/red/a/nobackup/vision/anju/affine_tranformation/tool/homepage.png')

image = Label(backGround, image=getImage)

backGround.grid()
image.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
#image.attributes('-alpha',1.0)
image['bg'] = image['bg']

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No `tkinter` widget can be transparent/partially transparent.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. How can I prevent the background from interfering with the tkinter application?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want to achieve.